# Building android application using ant

Tags: android, ant

I need to compile my application with additional libraries. The problem is that I do not want to include external libraries inside my application.

In Eclipse I have the option to toggle if I want a selected library/source to be exported with my application or not.

How could I modify ant script to simply skip the given libraries, and to not include them when building apk?

Also, any information regarding how adt plugin creates apk would be nice.

Comment: if I understand : you need a library at compile time, but you don't need it at runtime ?

Comment: It's like this: I have a libraries called 'A', 'B' & 'C'. I need to have at a runtime only 'B'.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [libraryjars](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#manual/usage.html) option in Proguard. It skips the jar from the output. Quoting the documentation.

> Specifies the library jars (or wars, ears, zips, or directories) of the application to be processed. The files in these jars will not be included in the output jars.

The [proguard android](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#manual/examples.html) example can get you started on the config file. Proguard can also be invoked from ant.

Comment: Interesting. Does Eclipse/ADT uses this while building apk?

Comment: It depends. If proguard is enabled for your project, eclipse will use it when you select the 'Export' option from the drop down menu that appears when you right-click on the project. Look for the property proguard.config on the project.properties file of your android project to check if proguard is enabled. If the proguard.config key is not available, add it - proguard.config=proguard-project.txt. Define the proguard rules under proguard-project.txt.